# Stata - Link observations if at least one of several variables have same value

Tags: stata, categorization

I have the following data structure ([Picture of structure of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUggk.png)), where each row represents a household and the variable "group1" identifies the classroom of child 1 in the household, "group2" the classroom of child 2, and so on. It is worth noting that there are around 3000 groups in total, as these are households all over the country. 
I need to categorize households as belonging to the same group if at least one of the "group" variables have the same value (i.e., if at least one of their children go to the same class). This can happen if, for two households, "group1" = "group1", but also if "group1" = "group2", or "group3", etc.

I have experimented using `inlist`and looping through all "group values", but haven't arrived anywhere.

I will be extremely grateful for any help you can offer.

Comment: Pictures don't help as much as you hope. Stata 14.2 up or 15.1 up include `dataex` as a way to produce data examples helpful in forums. If you are using an earlier version `ssc inst dataex` first.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do with data in a long layout, with one observation per child. You can then group households with children in the same class (as identified in the `group` variable) using `group_id` (from SSC):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long household float(group1 group2 group3 group4)
101 15 16  .  .
102 13 14 15 17
103 11 17  .  .
104 33 34 35  .
105 34 37  .  .
end

reshape long group, i(household) j(child)
drop if mi(group)

clonevar hhgroup = household
group_id hhgroup, matchby(group)

reshape wide group, i(household) j(child)

list
```

and the results

```
. list

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     | househ~d   group1   group2   group3   group4   hhgroup |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      101       15       16        .        .       101 |
  2. |      102       13       14       15       17       101 |
  3. |      103       11       17        .        .       101 |
  4. |      104       33       34       35        .       104 |
  5. |      105       34       37        .        .       104 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+

.
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Robert. However, I don't think this generates the desired result. For example, household 103's hhgroup is listed as 101, but these two households don't have any group in common. Household 103 should be linked to household 102 (they both have a child in group 17). This also seems to force households to belong to one group only. For example, House 102 is connected to 101 and 103, whereas household 101 is only connected to household 102.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: As you observe, `household` 101 and 102 share a group 15 so by your rules they belong in the same `hhgroup`. The same is true for `household` 102 and 103 as they both have a group 17. So `hhgroup` 101 correctly groups households 101 and 102 and 102 and 103. If this is not what you want, in what `hhgroup` would you put household 102?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed household 101 and 102 belong to the same group, but 101 and 103 don´t because none of their children are in the same group. What I need is a way that identifies to which households each household is linked, where these links are determined by whether any of the children in household i is in the same group as any of the children in household j. The requirement for being linked is to have at least one child in the same group. Hence 101 and 103 do not belong to the same hhgroup.

Comment: You haven't addressed my question, is 102 grouped with 101 or 103? If these links are to be represented by a single `hhgroup` variable, then what you want is not possible. Why don't you follow Nicks advice and post a representative data example using `dataex` (from SSC) and include variable(s) that would show how you would like these households to be grouped.